# Problems with running sqlplus64 == SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible

Tags: server, proxy, oracle

Running Ubuntu 14.10

I installed the Oracle Client version 11_2 but when I try to run `sqlplus64`I get:

```
Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible**

ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/files

ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_HOME
```

Another peculiar thing. If I try to run `sudo sqlplus64`:

I get a `command not found` message though that may not be important right now.

I've tried setting http_proxy the same way that is set on the Ubuntu network settings [and it's working, as I'm typing this from the ubuntu machine] but the error message still says my http_proxy is not accessible for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but Ubuntu 14.10 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Found an obscure answer and it worked

unset no_proxy

That did it for me, sqlplus64 ran like a charm